# Sql queries executed at a give time window on oracle server

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to know how to find SQL queries executed at specified time window. E.g what queries oracle was executing on 2011-07-11:15:20:10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.sql_id,dbms_lob.substr(b.sql_text,4000,1) from dba_hist_active_sess_history a, dba_hist_sqltext b
where sample_time between to_date('20110711:15:20','yyyymmdd:hh24:mi')
and to_date('20110711:15:21','yyyymmdd:hh24:mi') and b.sql_id=a.sql_id
union all

select a.sql_id ,dbms_lob.substr(b.sql_text,4000,1)from v$active_session_history a ,v$sqlarea b
where sample_time between to_date('20110711:15:20','yyyymmdd:hh24:mi') and
to_date('20110711:15:21','yyyymmdd:hh24:mi') and b.sql_id=a.sql_id
```

[Read more: Oracle SQL History | eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7270645_oracle-sql-history.html#ixzz1fxkhcMUz)

Comment: Sorry Daniel, For asking again the above is not working. Can you help with actual working query.

Comment: select a.sql_id,substr(b.sql_text,1,1000) from dba_hist_active_sess_history a, dba_hist_sqltext b where a.sample_time between to_date('11082011:02:22:19','mmddyyyy:hh:mi:ss') and to_date('11082011:02:24:19','mmddyyyy:hh:mi:ss') and b.sql_id=a.sql_id 
union all

Comment: select c.sql_id,substr(d.sql_text,1,1000)from v$active_session_history c ,v$sqlarea d where c.sample_time between to_date('11082011:02:22:19','mmddyyyy:hh:mi:ss') and to_date('11082011:02:24:19','mmddyyyy:hh:mi:ss') and d.sql_id=c.sql_id
                *
Error at line 1 ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression